# PowerShell script doesn't get the text from the out file

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

The following code doesn't put text into the out file when I run it. How do I correctly add the out file so that all the text from the shell gets copied to the out file?

```
$connection = "localhost:19000"
$timeToRun = 60
$maxStabilizationTimeSecs = 180
$waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec = 10
$serviceName = "fabric:/OnServiceFabric.Policy.Deploy/PolicyService"
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $connection
Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario -TimeToRunMinute $timeToRun -MaxServiceStabilizationTimeoutSec $maxStabilizationTimeSecs -WaitTimeBetweenFaultsSec $waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec -ServiceName $serviceName -PartitionKindSingleton
Pause | out-file c:\temp\results.txt
```

Comment: Is Pause actually on a new line or was it just wrapped?

Comment: it is wrapped .I actually took out the pause out at first but it still didn't work I just added the pause later so i could copy the text

Comment: The answer Restless just posted is what I'm thinking is happening but that would mean Pause is NOT wrapped? Your statement kind of contradicts itself though. Just to clarify, the `|` (pipeline) needs to be on the SAME line as your Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario command for it to pipe the output.

Comment: thanks @Deadly-Bagel . running the test right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Output of `Invoke-SeviceFabricFailoverTestScenario` in your `results.txt`, you're breaking the Pipeline-Data by using `pause`.

If your really need `pause` then try something like:

```
$connection = "localhost:19000"
$timeToRun = 60
$maxStabilizationTimeSecs = 180
$waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec = 10
$serviceName = "fabric:/OnServiceFabric.Policy.Deploy/PolicyService"
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $connection
$data = Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario -TimeToRunMinute $timeToRun -MaxServiceStabilizationTimeoutSec $maxStabilizationTimeSecs -WaitTimeBetweenFaultsSec $waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec -ServiceName $serviceName -PartitionKindSingleton 

 Pause 

 $data | out-file c:\temp\results.txt
```

Comment: will check and let you know . Thanks @restless1987

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = "localhost:19000"
$timeToRun = 60
$maxStabilizationTimeSecs = 180
$waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec = 10
$serviceName = "fabric:/OnServiceFabric.Policy.Deploy/PolicyService"
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $connection
Invoke-ServiceFabricFailoverTestScenario -TimeToRunMinute $timeToRun `
    -MaxServiceStabilizationTimeoutSec $maxStabilizationTimeSecs `
    -WaitTimeBetweenFaultsSec $waitTimeBetweenFaultsSec `
    -ServiceName $serviceName `
    -PartitionKindSingleton | out-file c:\temp\results.txt
```

The pipeline needs to be on the same line as the command, otherwise it's interpreting it as a new command.

Additionally you can use backticks to tell the line to continue on the next line for neater code.